# How to make a RectTransform follow another RectTransform that is located under a different parent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am trying to make a RectTransform with default anchor settings follow a RectTransform that is right-bottom aligned non-stretch. However, there is always an offset between them.

I have tried GetWorldRect().center and transform it into a WorldPoint with no luck. Using transform. position only works when both UIElements are anchored with default values.

Can anyone help fill the following method body?

```
public static void FollowRectTransform(this RectTransform source, RectTransform target)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Parent Constraint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ParentConstraint.html) component to make one Gameobject act as though it is the child of another GameObject for purposes of positioning and scale, including RectTransform.